# Xcode 10 Main Thread Checker: Cordova Camera Plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, camera, ios13

Following iOS13 release, I'm testing a hybrid app using Cordova.  Launching the camera is very slow and generates the following:

=================================================================

Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIImagePickerController init]

PID: 1347, TID: 618928, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos, QoS: 0

Backtrace:

4                                       0x0000000100f1bba0 +[CDVCameraPicker createFromPictureOptions:] + 124

5                                       0x0000000100f15d54 -[CDVCamera showCameraPicker:withOptions:] + 108

6                                       0x0000000100f15570 __25-[CDVCamera takePicture:]_block_invoke_2 + 336

7   AVFoundation                        0x00000001b76178f8 2BC0C357-314E-3AE8-B006-C28528B87512 + 710904

8   TCC                                 0x00000001b35dfbf8 85A762AF-99DB-3B4C-B24B-09600CC17196 + 7160

9   TCC                                 0x00000001b35e3de4 85A762AF-99DB-3B4C-B24B-09600CC17196 + 24036

10  libxpc.dylib                        0x00000001acfe3804 79A1F1AD-9CB4-3334-91D9-E1ED6B1032A3 + 104452

11  libxpc.dylib                        0x00000001acfd72c4 79A1F1AD-9CB4-3334-91D9-E1ED6B1032A3 + 53956

12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010109b3b4 _dispatch_client_callout3 + 20

13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001010b7000 _dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke + 392

14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001010ada8c _dispatch_kevent_worker_thread + 1436

15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001ad0e6adc _pthread_wqthread + 336

16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001ad0ecc7c start_wqthread + 8

Xcode 10.3
cordova-plugin-camera version 4.1.0

running on iPhone X, iOS13

Eventually the camera opens and allows me to take a photo but the UI is not displayed correctly afterwards.  I've tried creating a brand new app with only the camera plugin added and the same thing happens.

How this can be resolved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would seem that UIImagePickerController needs to be called in the UI Thread.
Fortunately, the code is already ready for that change!

Just move the cameraPicker init section into the main thread section:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  // UI MainThread execution
 CDVCameraPicker* cameraPicker = [CDVCameraPicker createFromPictureOptions:pictureOptions];
 weakSelf.pickerController = cameraPicker;

cameraPicker.delegate = weakSelf;
cameraPicker.callbackId = command.callbackId;
// we need to capture this state for memory warnings that dealloc this object
cameraPicker.webView = weakSelf.webView;
  ...
}
```

D.

Comment: FYI, this change is in Plugins/CDVCamera.m, showCameraPicker().

Comment: After changing the code as mentioned above, you will have to (1) remove the iOS platform, (2) re-add the platform again, (3) build the project